# android service communicates with other class instances

Tags: android, service

first let me describe the logic.

1. User turn on Photos Upload button to launch a transfer service to upload local photos to server.
2. When the app was left invisible to user. still monitor the local photos, if camera new photos, upload it immediately. I use this [ContentResolver resolution](http://www.jessechen.net/blog/how-does-google-plus-instant-upload-work/) to implement the function.
3. after terminate the app, user may take new photos, when restart the app, scan the local sd-card and upload those new photo.

Here is my question:

When should I put `step2` into Service in case the activity was destroied. should I use another service to implement the `step3` business.

you can find [the source on Github](https://github.com/Logan676/seadroid/blob/lg2/src/com/seafile/seadroid2/BrowserActivity.java)

see the source snippet below:

```
    Intent txIntent = new Intent(this, TransferService.class);
    startService(txIntent);
    Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "start TransferService");

    // bind transfer service
    Intent bIntent = new Intent(this, TransferService.class);
    bindService(bIntent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "try bind TransferService");

    Intent monitorIntent = new Intent(this, FileMonitorService.class);
    startService(monitorIntent);

    Intent cameraUploadIntent = new Intent(this, CameraUploadService.class);
    startService(cameraUploadIntent);

    this.getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(
        MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, false, cameraUploadObserver);
    `
```

So should I put cameraUploadObserver in service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

follow steps to implement the requirement:

1. create a service to fulfill the two parts of requirements
2. UI button to trigger the service
3. inside service class, register a Content Observer to detect camera event, the event files onChange() method, so you can upload photo in onChange() method
4. register a Transfer service, bind the connection and use that to upload all local photos under onStartCommand() method.

[go to the github site](https://github.com/Logan676/seadroid/blob/lg2/src/com/seafile/seadroid2/sync/CameraUploadService.java) to view the whole project.