# Is it possible to discover if picture was taken?

Tags: android, image, android-camera

I would like to discover that picture was taken by default camera app. Just like Google plus discovers it and upload it to server. I failed in finding it in documentation. Does anybody have a hint where to find this kind of information?

Comment: Take a looksee at this previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/230643/android-api-for-detecting-new-media-from-inbuilt-camera-mic

Comment: Thanks Marijn it looks helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have 2 things as far as I know

1. An intent when media is added, which is the below I believe. I'm not really sure how much use it is in all cases, you should have to try it out :)

   ```
   Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE
   ```
2. You can keep an eye on the special kind of content you wish to know about when it changes. See for an exmple here: http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.nl/2008/03/observing-content.html